# Display amount each month from start date until end date

Tags: sql

I need help to write ANSI SQL (Oracle database). I have a table called 'opportunity' which has below columns and data:

```
|  Opp Name  |  Amount  |  Is Recurring  |  Start Date  |   End Date  |
|  Emily     |  £350    |       Y        |  11-AUG-2017 |  15-JUL-2018|
|  Andrew    |  £1200   |       N        |  10-MAR-2017 |  10-MAR-2017|
```

If an opportunity is recurring (it's recurring flag = 'Y'), the query should return amount for each month beginning from Start Date until End Date has been reached. That is, one row of data per month. If the opportunity is not recurring (recurring flag ='N'), only one row of data is required. [In database, if recurring flag ='N' then End Date will be same as Start Date]

Here is the desired output:

```
|Opp Name | Amount | MONTH |
|  Emily  |  £350  |  AUG  |
|  Emily  |  £350  |  SEP  | 
|  Emily  |  £350  |  OCT  | 
|  Emily  |  £350  |  NOV  | 
|  Emily  |  £350  |  DEC  | 
|  Emily  |  £350  |  JAN  | 
|  Emily  |  £350  |  FEB  | 
|  Emily  |  £350  |  MAR  | 
|  Emily  |  £350  |  APR  | 
|  Emily  |  £350  |  MAY  | 
|  Emily  |  £350  |  JUN  | 
|  Emily  |  £350  |  JUL  | 
|  Andrew |  £1200 |  MAR  |
```

I am not sure how to approach this. Any help would be much appreciated.